# Spirituality is making me anhedoniac!

Tags: spiritual-materialism

I only find pleasure in working on my goals and achieving something every day.

Female bodies don't seem much attractive anymore but out of habit I masterbate after every 3 days just for the sake of it. I don't even get an orgasm after ejaculation. It is bland. Boring. And I have lost a lot of attraction for all the mainstream things.

This all have started happening after I did 10 days Vipassana Meditation Course. Everything feels empty.

I only find excitement in my work and time spend with close friends.

Any thoughts? I am worried about my anhedoniac sexual activities as I am still in my 20s

Comment: You write "I'm worried" but the question isn't clear -- e.g. there's nothing with a question mark. If someone were to answer based on their personal experience and/or a reference to doctrine, then what should be in the answer, how to assess whether it's an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Anhedonia is a [diagnosable medical condition](https://www.webmd.com/depression/what-is-anhedonia#1). Please consult a doctor for evaluating your condition. Your spiritual practice might have revealed a medical condition, especially if nothing gives you pleasure. Spiritual practice does lessen craving, yet normally other joys blossom accompanied by happiness in seclusion and meditation. Continued practice should strengthen spiritual bliss. If you are not experiencing spiritual happiness, consult your spiritual teacher as well.

Answer (score 1):

Great achievement, congratulation. Most don't archive it even after lifetime practice. It's just that it is mostly not for sure, so continue further to a point where possible joy in ordinary work or association with others also fade away and developing Dhamma remains as refuge.

The younger the better. No need to follow the old never ending practitioner.

*[Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks or to put into other world binding relations but for an escape from this wheel.]*

Answer (score 0):

Buddhist meditation, namely, anapanasati, is for the development of a spiritual happiness that is superior to and requires an absence of sensual pleasure.

Since sexual desires are often a significant obstacle would-be meditators, you might have a head start.